# DataFormatString Working On My Local Machine, But Not When Upload to Host

Tags: asp.net, gridview

DataFormatString Working On My Local Machine, But Not When Upload to Host. tarih column in gridview. Why and how can i fix it ?

> asp:BoundField DataField="tarih" HeaderText="tarih"
>   SortExpression="tarih" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss}"
>   HtmlEncode="False"

results:
On local: 11.05.2015 18:44:07
On Host:  5/11/2015 6:56:03 PM +03:00

Comment: The dateformat is probably dependent on the setting of the 'locale' in the machine where it runs.

Comment: @jcoppens is there any other way to convert date ?

Answer (score 1):

ETA: There was a miscommunication, I thought you wanted 5/11/2015 6:56:03 PM  NOT 11.05.2015 18:44:07. Your DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss}"
is going to give you the first (which you said you don't want), en-US globalization will also give you that.

Change web.config globalization settings to:

```
<globalization culture="tr-Tr" />
```

OR put this on your page:

```
<%@ Page Culture="tr-Tr" %>
```

Change your DataFormatString to:
    DataFormatString="{0:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss}"

*My original answer would work to switch the opposite way:
You could try changing the globalization settings in your web.config file:*

```
    <globalization culture="en-US" />
```

*See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508(v=vs.85).aspx.
You could also consider changing your date format to YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss since that is the international standard datetime format.*

Comment: Do you have any cultural information on your page that could be overriding the web.config?

Comment: public void tarihYaz(string id)
        {
            var info = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Turkey Standard Time");
            DateTimeOffset localServerTime = DateTimeOffset.Now;
            DateTimeOffset istanbulTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(localServerTime, info);

            //OutputLabel.Text += istanbulTime;
            baglanti2.Open();
            komut2.CommandText = "UPDATE BilgisayarDuyuru SET tarih='" + istanbulTime + "'  WHERE id='" + id + "'";
            komut2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            baglanti2.Close();            
        }

Comment: Is your host running on Turkish globalization? Because that does not support  month first datetimes. In fact it looks like it would not even support universal datetime. Try using something like DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo (used with parsing) which is culture independent, and look at this website: http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html

Comment: it's hard for me to understand. How can i use DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo in my code ?

Comment: Just to double check, did you put the globalization in between the <System.web></System.web> tags in web.config? When you say "It didn't work," can you please explain what didn't work and what happened when you tried?

Comment: Yes i did. It still shown  5/11/2015 6:56:03 PM +03:00 instead of 11.05.2015 18:44:07 and my host is not running in Turkey. its http://www.aspspider.com and my site is http://aspspider.info/wanxpy/WebForm1.aspx

Comment: Okay so I thought you wanted 5/11/2015 6:56:03 PM +03:00 NOT 11.05.2015 18:44:07. Please see my revised answer.

Comment: Things are more complicated then i assume. Can i send you my source code ? Because it still not working :(

Comment: Yep! Zip it up and email it to me Whitneyhaddow@gmail.com or upload on GitHub. I will try to get it working tomorrow (it's night for me here).

Comment: I've noticed a thing. In local, sql server is 2014 but on host 2008. Can it be the problem ?

Comment: It could be. Check out this link, they are having the same problem as you! Is it possible to upgrade the host SQL server to test it out?https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/7572ac18-09b4-4f63-ad18-bd04e108b680/datetime-format